# What is the probability of chosing the hotels in the given way.

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

The question is as follows,
20 persons arrive in a town having 3 hotels X, Y and Z, if each person randomly choses one of these hotels then what is the probability that at least two of them go in hotel X , at least one in hotel Y and at least one in hotel Z.

Answer (score 0):

Using compliment:
$$P(S)=1-P(F)=1-[P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(Y=0)+P(Z=0)-P(X=0,Y=0,Z=20)-P(X=0,Y=20,Z=0)-P(X=1,Y=0,Z=19)-P(X=1,Y=19,Z=0)].$$

Comment: That's how I also did, can there be any other approach?